# Laravel: Store error messages in database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Any one know how to send error messages to database in laravel which generate from app/exceptions/handler.php ?

I need to send what error massages generated in report() method to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested doing this manually, you can do something as following.

**Step 1 -**
Create a model to store errors that has a DB structure as following.

```
class Error extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id' , 'code' , 'file' , 'line' , 'message' , 'trace' ];
}
```

**Step 2**
Locate the App/Exceptions/Handler.php file, include Auth, and the Error model you created. and replace the report function with the following code.

> ```
> public function report(Exception $exception) {
>
>     // Checks if a user has logged in to the system, so the error will be recorded with the user id
>     $userId = 0;
>     if (Auth::user()) {
>         $userId = Auth::user()->id;
>     }
>
>     $data = array(
>         'user_id' => $userId,
>         'code' => $exception->getCode(),
>         'file' => $exception->getFile(),
>         'line' => $exception->getLine(),
>         'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
>         'trace' => $exception->getTraceAsString(),
>     );
>
>     Error::create($data);
>     parent::report($exception);
> }
> ```

(I am demonstrating this using laravel 5.6)

Answer (score 1):

Because Laravel [uses Monolog](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging) for handling logging it seems that writing [Monolog Handler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#handlers) would be the cleanest way.

I was able to find something that exists already, please have a look at [monolog-mysql package](https://github.com/markhilton/monolog-mysql). I did not use it, so I don't know whether it works and if it works well, but it's definitely good starting point.